# twig attribute class

Tags: theming, 8

I want to add multiple class to my `{{item}}` twig template. The following code

```
{% set item = item|merge({'#attributes': { 'class': 'project-label'}}) %}
```

sets only one class ... how can I assign multiple class ? can i do something like this

```
{% set item = item|merge({'#attributes': { 'class': 'project-label'}}),
({'#attributes': { 'class': 'project-term{{ loop.index }}'}}`)%}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173718/how-to-add-attribute-to-element-in-twig-before-render)?

Comment: yes ... the thing is I want to use the {{loop.index}} on the second class

Answer (score 1):

Put the classes in an array:

```
{%
  set itemclasses = [
    'project-label',
    'project-term' ~ loop.index,
  ]
%}
```

And add the array to attributes:

```
{% set item = item|merge({'#attributes': { 'class': itemclasses } }) %}
```

Comment: the loop.index is not looping --- i does print out the classes as expected but the  loop.index count is missing.

Comment: Did you place the code to set `itemclasses` also in the loop?

Comment: yes the  `itemclasses` is within a for loop

Comment: This is what i have

  `{%
  set itemclasses = [
    'project-label',
    'project-term' ~ loop.index,
  ]
%}
  {% for child in children %}
    {% set item = attribute(element, child) %}
    {% set item = item|merge ({'#attributes': { 'class': itemclasses }}) %}
    <li >  
        {{ item }}
     </li>
  {% endfor %}
`

Comment: You have to start with the for loop before you set the itemclasses. Outside of the loop the loop variables are undefined.